# MLFlow Projects can't find conda executable

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, mlflow

I am following the tutorial on MLFlow website. I was able to run the train.py and mlflow ui worked fine. Packaging the project tries to use env variable  MLFLOW_CONDA_HOME but can't find conda.
I have tried setting the variable to the path of anaconda3/condabin but it doesn't seem to find my executable. This is the error I get:
 ERROR mlflow.cli: === Could not find Conda executable at /anaconda3/condabin\bin/conda. Ensure Conda is installed as per the inst
ructions at https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html. You can also configure MLflow to look for a specific Conda executable by setting the MLFLOW_CONDA_HOME environment variable
 to the path of the Conda executable ===

Adding \bin/conda at the end of my path seems to be the problem, I am not sure why mlflow is doing it. I even tried setting it to my python.exe in my conda env, but no luck. I can't find bin/conda folder in my Anaconda folder anywhere.

Comment: I think it should be `/bin/conda` not `\bin/conda`

Comment: Exactly, but mlflow is adding the \bin/conda part to my path when I run mlflow run examples/sklearn_elasticnet_wine -P alpha=0.42
And I don't even have bin/conda folder!

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by running it from Anaconda Prompt. Make sure mlflow is installed in anaconda first as well, nothing else. But the problem then is that it's not well compatible on windows, you would need to split into two steps, activate the conda environment and then run with --no-conda as mentioned here https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/2674

Answer (score 1):

MLflow 1.5 was just released today.

It doesn't specifically mention it in the github notes, but I had the same issue, where it affixed \bin/conda, and now it doesn't do that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have conda environment then you can execute the following command from your terminal

```
mlflow run <enter your local directory name> --no-conda -P alpha=0.5
```

This should solve the issues with the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing the MLFLOW_CONDA_HOME environment variable alltogether. Make sure you have added the path to the conda executable to your PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solutions (the fastest one, in my opinion).

Key points:

1. The project virtual environment should be created with conda.
2. Use pip to install MLFlow.

Follow the steps for Windows:

1. Install miniconda (in my case, version 3)
2. Set conda bat file (installation path + condabin dir + conda.bat) in PATH
3. Create your project without virtual environment (in my case, I set in PyCharm conda instead of venv and it did not create any virtual environment, just added some external libraries), at least not in the project directory.
4. Create conda virtual environment manually in the project directory. In your project directory, execute `conda create -n venv` and follow the instructions (I used default for all the questions there).
5. Open a terminal and activate conda virtual environment. If you use PyCharm, you will be positioned properly, otherwise just prompt yourself in the project directory. Execute `conda activate venv` where venv is my virtual environment created at point 4.
6. Execute `python -m pip install mlflow`

If you want to test it, you can try one of the tests from MLFlow. E.g., you can use `mlflow run https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow-example.git -P alpha=5.0`

In my case, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf` and get an error saying `Could not find Conda executable conda` then try to define the environment variable `MLFLOW_CONDA_HOME` in `spark-env.sh` as Spark doesn't recognize variables defined elsewhere. Also make sure to use the absolute path for the Conda executable.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue within a kubernetes deployment with miniconda3 as the base image. Fixed this by setting the MLFLOW_CONDA_HOME env variable to "/opt/conda/"